# UIWebView Won't Load Certain Website

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I'm having a bit of a problem with the UIWebView. I created my UIWebView in Interface Builder and created an outlet as tasksWebView. I also linked it to my View Controller as a delegate. I want to load http://www.taskyo.com, but when I try to load it, I just get a white page. It works fine in Mobile Safari, so I'm confused as to what the problem is. To make it even more perplexing, when I replace http://www.taskyo.com with http://www.google.com, it works fine. If I try to access http://www.taskyo.com via Google, I get a white page when I click on the URL. My code is below:

Header File

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppThirdViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *tasksWebView;

- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)goHome:(id)sender;

@end
```

Implementation File

```
#import "AppThirdViewController.h"

@interface AppThirdViewController ()

@end

@implementation AppThirdViewController
@synthesize tasksWebView = _tasksWebView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self goHome:self];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    _tasksWebView = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
{
    [_tasksWebView goBack];
}

- (IBAction)goHome:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *tasksURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:/www.taskyo.com/"];
    NSURLRequest *tasksRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:tasksURL];
    [_tasksWebView loadRequest:tasksRequest];
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"Started to load!");
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"Finished loading!");
}

@end
```

In my console, I get the following output:

```
Started to load
Finished loading!
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to the problem?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Fixed - see my answer below.

Comment: Did you try with another page such as www.google.com? I can load and display your page in a UIWebView without any problem. Therefore look at how you are displaying the view controller.

Comment: I pasted your code into a simple test app and the page loaded for both the simulator and a device.  If other pages load for you, I'm not sure what to say....  Are you going through a caching server?

Comment: @MartinH Yeah, I tried with Google and it loaded fine... I'm just using a simple storyboard - my app is a tab bar app; one of the tabs loads a view with the UIWebView I'm having problems with...

Comment: Your website loads fine in my UIWebView. Sorry no idea at all why you can load google but not this one when it works for the rest of us, cannot think of anything other than what Philip says (unless you are returning NO to this site in shouldStartLoadWithRequest).

Comment: @MartinH Thanks for your help. I'll try to rewrite my view controller from scratch and see if it works. Something of note: three of my five tabs load UIWebViews, all using more or less the same code. The other two tabs work perfectly, but if I replace the address with taskyo.com, they don't.

Comment: So you have 3 UIWebViews, and if you change the address of one to taskyo.com the others stop working? That is significant. We need more info on the program structure.

Comment: @MartinH No, I'm saying if I change the address of one to taskyo.com, the one whose address I changed stops working.

Comment: Meaning that a UIViewController whose address is taskyo.com isn't working.

Comment: I copied and pasted this code into another test app I made and the code worked fine. That means that it's a problem with my current app. I'll try to rewrite the view controller and see if it works.

Comment: I rewrote the view controller and remade the view in Interface Builder and it still doesn't work. I confirmed that all of the outlets were set up correctly, because it still loads www.google.com. The test app still works, so I don't know what's up...

Answer (score 1):

As of writing this answer, Taskyo.com is not available. (Even my web browser can't open the links you have provided).

Comment: Ooops... it looks like I made a typo on one of the links. It's still spelled correctly in the code, though, so my question still remains the same...

Comment: Hmm.. OK, I see. Strange, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Is taskyo.com a new domain? Perhaps some nameserver don't know it yet.
(That wouldn't explain, why you are able to open the page on Mobile Safari).

Comment: Doesn't look like it... from the creator's blog post (http://www.dannyroa.com/2011/07/18/taskyo-access-google-tasks-on-your-mobile-device/), it looks like it was from July 2011...

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the site has invalid JavaScript or HTML. Mobile Safari may not be using the exact library versions that your app is. For example, the W3C validator shows several issues with your page: [Validate errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.taskyo.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

The first thing you should try is to strip the web page to a simple "Hello World" message and then try adding back content to see where the problem is. It's also possible that you are getting stale, cached HTML from an older revision. I like adding a "?rand=2" parameter, with an incrementing value, to make sure I'm getting the current file.

Comment: It's not my page... I'm just trying to load it as one of the features of my app...

Answer (score 0):

After more testing, I realized that there wasn't a problem with my code, but with the actual app bundle itself. I uninstalled it from the simulator and rebuilt it and it's working now. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Does anybody have any idea why it happened, though? I don't want my users to have to reinstall the app regularly if I can help it...

Comment: *Update* Happened once again. It worked after I uninstalled and rebuilt, but I'd prefer to fix this so that, as I said above, my users don't have to keep uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: Update - It seems to happen every other time I run the app or one in every three times. What could the problem be?

Comment: If the issue isn't actually fixed, then you probably shouldn't mark an answer as accepted, especially one of your own answers.